# Distinct colors for headlabel and taillabel in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is it possible to set distinct colors for headlabel and taillabel in graphviz?
Using labelfontcolor I can set one common color for both of them but I need different colors (something like headfontcolor and tailfontcolor but these attributes don't exist).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can succeed doing this using the HTML-style labels in graphviz (you can find lots of information on this page: http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html), and particularly the `font` one:

```
digraph test
{
    A -> B
    [
        taillabel = <<font color="red">tail</font>>
        label     = <<font color="green">middle</font>>
        headlabel = <<font color="blue">head</font>>
    ]
}
```

This code will produce the following diagram:

[image]